# z-index is not respected

Tags: css, z-index

I have this styles:

```
header{
   width:400px;
   min-height:640px;
   background:#9B9B76;
   float:left;
   z-index:1000;  /*high*/
}
nav{
   width:100%;
   z-index:1001;  /*highest*/
}

nav a{
   float:left;
   width:80%;
   padding:10%;
   font-size:20px;
}
nav a:hover{
   background:#997548;
}
.LevelCnt_1{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    z-index:1;       /*Lowest*/
    position:absolute;
    left:400px;
    background:#baafa9; 
}
```

the problem is that visually .LevelCnt_1 stays on top of header if I set `left:0px`

why is this happening?

Comment: try putting `position:relative` to the header

Comment: z-index only works when the element is positioned. TRy adding a position statement to the CSS and see what happens.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`z-index` only work with `position relative, absolute & fixed`. So, give `position:relative` to your `header & nav` DIV .

Like this

```
header{
   width:400px;
   min-height:640px;
   background:#9B9B76;
   float:left;
   z-index:1000;  /*high*/
position:relative
}
nav{
   width:100%;
   z-index:1001;  /*highest*/
position:relative
}
```